# Open presentation in PowerPoint 2013 via VBS script

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint

This VBS works fine with PowerPoint 2010, 2003

```
Set pptApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
pptApp.Visible = True
pptApp.WindowState = 2
Set ppt = pptApp.Presentations.Open("c:\temp\test.pptx")
```

However PowerPoint 2013 has a problem with last line

```
Unspecified error
```

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs, if there is a lack of some privilages. Check it in properties->security of this file.

Please also note, that Microsoft has headed for using Visual Studio for Applications instead of VBA making VBA not longer recommended.

Comment: Don't think so, I can open this PPTX from PowerPoint.